# IIS 6.5 application hangs - strange behavior

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, iis-6, asp.net, application-pools

Ok, here are the symptoms in chronological order:

(iis 6.5 - asp.net 2.0 - windows server 2003)

- Application pool drops all requests. (dropped, and abandoned by reqQueue)
- Trying to log into application from VPN connection only shows hourglass, never loads
- Logging into the server and opening app on local host: applications in app pool run fine
- Reset app pool
- Application runs again for 5 minutes then starts hanging again.
- Create a new app pool
- Move the application to this pool.
- Application runs again for 5 minutes then starts hanging again in new app pool.
- Restart the server
- Applications run for about a week until same scenario restarts again

This was not happening until recently about a week after a new release was installed and deployed on the server. Minor coding changed were implemented.

- Changed the redirection of my login page from a 'Server.Transfer' to a 'Response.Redirect'
- Added a section to grab data from the DB to a asp:label.

Stuff that hasn't worked:

- Creating new app poool
- Recycling App Pool
- Restarting App Pool

More Strange behavior:

- Windows Installer now freezing up and not allowing me to install a text .msi i created
- Screen hangs when I try to add a new Performance Counter

Error logs not showing any thing that i can see to cause this problem.
I will add more details if I think they can help.